# Wordpress (Free) news themes

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I made  a website by wordpress (online). I've tried free news themes but in these themes, slides don't work. And all themes aren't responsive, namely toggle button doesn't work. What can I solve these problems? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend you the following site if you want it to be a great WordPress web site. For little money you get great themes here: https://themeforest.net/category/wordpress

Personally, I would recommend you a theme that works with Elementor Builder. These can be edited very easily and are responsive.

Is not meant to be an advertisement but this is my favorite theme: https://themeforest.net/item/jupiter-multipurpose-responsive-theme/5177775